# Flat JSON in Jackson for class/record/value object with one field

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

I have a Java record with one field only:

```java
public record AggregateId(UUID id) {}
```

And a class with the `AggregateId` field (other fields removed for readability)

```java
public class Aggregate {

    public final AggregateId aggregateId;

    @JsonCreator
    public Aggregate(
            @JsonProperty("aggregateId") AggregateId aggregateId
    ) {
        this.aggregateId = aggregateId;
    }
}
```

The implementation above serialize and deserialize JSON with given example:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String content = """
        {
           "aggregateId": {
                "id": "3f61aede-83dd-4049-a6ff-337887b6b807"
            }
        }
        """;
Aggregate aggregate = objectMapper.readValue(content, Aggregate.class);
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(aggregate));
```

How could I change Jackson config to replace JSON by that:

```json
{
    "aggregateId": "3f61aede-83dd-4049-a6ff-337887b6b807"
}
```

without giving up a separate class for `AggregateId` and access through fields, without getters?

I tried `@JsonUnwrapper` annotation, but this caused throws

```
Exception in thread "X" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
    Invalid type definition for type `X`: 
        Cannot define Creator parameter as `@JsonUnwrapped`: combination not yet supported at [Source: (String)"{
            "aggregateId": "3f61aede-83dd-4049-a6ff-337887b6b807"
        }"
```

or

```
Exception in thread "X" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
    Cannot define Creator property "aggregateId" as `@JsonUnwrapped`: 
        combination not yet supported at [Source: (String)"{
            "aggregateId": "3f61aede-83dd-4049-a6ff-337887b6b807"
        }"
```

*Jackson version: 2.13.1*

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.1"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.1"
}
```

**Of course, it's possible with a custom serializer/deserializer, but I'm looking for an easier solution because I have many different classes with a similar issue.**

Comment: `AggregateId` is failing to deserialize for me (the empty beans error, which was supposedly addressed with jackson 2.12). Am I missing something? Does your code as is produce that result?

Comment: @ernest_k I added a simple example with the default config of `ObjectMapper`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The combination of `@JsonUnwrapped` and `@JsonCreator` is not supported yet**, so we can generate a solution like this:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonUnwrapped;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

import java.util.UUID;

public class AggregateTest {

    static record AggregateId(@JsonProperty("aggregateId") UUID id) {}

    static class Aggregate {

        @JsonUnwrapped
        @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
        public final AggregateId _aggregateId;
        public final String otherField;

        @JsonCreator
        public Aggregate(@JsonProperty("aggregateId") UUID aggregateId,
                         @JsonProperty("otherField") String otherField) {
            this._aggregateId = new AggregateId(aggregateId);
            this.otherField = otherField;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String rawJson =
            "{\"aggregateId\": \"1f61aede-83dd-4049-a6ff-337887b6b807\"," +
                    "\"otherField\": \"İsmail Y.\"}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        Aggregate aggregate = objectMapper
                .readValue(rawJson, Aggregate.class);
        System.out.println(objectMapper
                .writeValueAsString(aggregate));
    }
}
```

Here we briefly get rid of the `@JsonUnwrapped` field.

We get the `UUID` with the name `aggregateId` and create an **`AggregateId` record**.

Detailed explanations about it:

- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1467
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1497

Comment: Your example works when I have only the `AggregateId` field in the `Aggregate`. When I add other field, for example `public final String otherField` I have an exception: ```com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type `...$Aggregate`: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for `...$Aggregate` (2 args), annotations: {interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator(mode=DEFAULT)} has no property name (and is not Injectable): can not use as property-based Creator```

Comment: I updated the answer to be more inclusive, if you want it to work in your case you can do it this way or you have to forgot `@JsonCreator` and add **getter / setter**, then it can be simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and links, now I understand the problem better. There seems to be no convenient solution, I have to make a compromise.